# Blue arrow overlay on Visual Studio 2012 project files

Tags: visual-studio, overlay, project

There are little blue arrows appearing on some of the files in my project in Visual Studio 2012 and I am not sure what they mean. And if I create a new class it does not have the icon on it.

Here's a screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdZB1.jpg

Comment: Are you connected to a version control system?  I am only guessing but I'd bet those are version control symbols.

Comment: @TimothyP, apart from technical part, thanks for reporting the duplicates, I am not sure how this mistake happened, I removed the duplicates.

Comment: btw how good is this imgur ! 7 years old link is still available :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It indicates that the source file is not stored in the project directory.  You get it with, for example, Project + Add Existing Item, select a file in another directory, click the arrow on the Add button and select "Add as Link".